# How can I make a delay in python without the camera video get affected and slowed?

Tags: python, opencv

Hope you are doing fine.

So my problem or question is actually more complicated than the title but I will try to keep it simple.

I have this code that runs on cam ( using OpenCV ) and will detect if a person wearing a mask or not, as far as detection go it performs very well ( I got the code from YouTube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax6P93r32KU&t=73s ).

In short I want the program to see if the person(with confidence > 95%) is wearing a mask or not, if he is wearing the mask a pop-up message will appear thanking him then the program will close.

In theory I've done all that, The problem is that when the person wears a mask the pop-up message will immediately appear before even the cam catch up !
or if the person isn't wearing a mask then starts to wear one the pop-up message will immediately appear also while he is wearing.

Ideally I would like to check if he is wearing the mask for 2 or 3 continues seconds then the pop-up will appear.

I tried using delay but it slows the camera so much and don't see what is happening, I tried append the confidence of wearing a mask into a list then take the average of the list but still didn't work.

So ideally :

confidence of person wearing mask = M

If M > 95% for 3 seconds:

```
   print(message(thank you))

    exit()
```

Hope you have an idea how to solve this, and I'm sorry if my explanation isn't obvious. I can show it with a live stream (discord) for anyone who is interested and didn't understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by making an empty list and set t1 = time.time() ( before the while True loop )

```
mask_list=[]
t1 = time.time()
```

and inside the loop I would take the reading for 4 seconds

```
mask_list.append(mask)

        if time.time() - t1 > 4: # when 4 seconds passes

            mask_avg = sum(mask_list) / len(mask_list)

            if mask_avg*100 > 90: # when the average of wearing a mask is > 90%

                # code for wearing a mask then exit()
            else :
                # code for NOT wearing a mask then exit()
```

I'm not sure if I'm allowed but I will post the code on GitHub if anyone wants to see the full code : https://github.com/Dalsallum/Login-System-With-Mask-Detection

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand properly, something like this should work. Let me know what happends or if you dont understand something. This code uses multiple threads as to not stop the video portion of code.

```
import time
import threading

wearingMaskBool = False

def checkPerson3Seconds():
        global wearingMaskBool
        #lets check the person 6 times     we will use multiple threads so the camera and the 3 second check code can run simpltaniously
        for i in range(6)
        if (M > 95%):
            #adding one if mask is worn
            wearingMask += 1
        else:
            #subtracting one if mask isnt worn
            wearingMask -= 1
        #wait half a second
        time.sleep(0.5)


    #checking if wearingMask == 6
    if wearingMask == 6:
        #execute code for person that is wearing mask
        #example
        # we can define the "wearingMaskBool" as a global and use it in out main script
        wearingMaskBool = True
    else:
        #execute code for person that isnt wearing mask
        #example
        # we can define the "wearingMaskBool" as a global and use it in out main script
        wearingMaskBool = False


#start thread aka staring the checkPerson3Seconds script
threading.Thread(target=checkPerson3Seconds(), daemon=True).start()

#after the script is ran if they are wearing a mask with a certainty of 95 percent of 3 seconds the the wearingMaskBool will be equal to true 
#if it fell below 95% it will be equal to false
```

Comment: Let me know what happenes, I would be glad to help you out, this seems interesting.

Comment: Actually it didn't work, any time.sleep() just makes the camera so slow even with the thread. I actually believe I made it work by taking a reading and store in a list, then after 4 seconds the code will check the average of the list and decide if he is wearing a mask or not. I tried the same approach before but didn't work then because I wasn't appending the percentages to list correctly before. I will do more testing to make sure but thank you for your effort. When I finish the code testing I will share it here ( GitHub link)

Comment: Ok, let me know.

Comment: Yeah I was able to solve it using a list and taking the average after 4 seconds, I will share the details with an answer.